# Webform: display image uploaded by user

Tags: webforms, media, commerce

I'm completely lost on how I could display an image uploaded by user on my webform...

What I'm planning to do is multistep webform that is also an order form. It has only filefield upload on first page, on the second page, that uploaded image should be presented/shown in a grid with few different image styles and static description to tell which is which so users can select those which they like. Only this feature is hitting me back and refusing to work so I could finish this project.

Any and all advices greatly appreciated.